# Read struct in array

Tags: swift

I've created a struct and appending it to an array. How do I read that struct inside the array?

```
struct TOitemData {
    let BestItem: String?
    let BestQty: Int?
    let BestTotal: Int?
}

class TObyItemVC: UIViewController{

    var TOitemArray: [TOitemData] = []
    TOitemArray.append(TOitemData(BestItem: "1/2 Chicken with chips", BestQty: 54, BestTotal: 4500))
    TOitemArray.append(TOitemData(BestItem: "Cheese hamburger and chips", BestQty: 45, BestTotal: 4210))

}
```

How can I get row two BestQty which is 45?

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html ? Or `first(where:)`/`firstIndex(where:)`? You want to get the second one, or get the second because what you know is "BestQty = 45"?

Comment: This question isn’t about reading a struct in an array. This question is about how to access an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply access the index you want to see (keep in mind that arrays start with index 0) and you're reading the struct. If you want to see a specific value of the struct, access it.

`TOitemArray[0]` to access the struct inside the position 0 (aka the first element of the array).
`arrayName[0].BestItem` to access the attribute `BestItem` of that struct.

Answer (score 1):

TObbyItemArray[1].BestQty to get the second row, and then the value of BestQty